# Staggered processing and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, timeout

I have an import script that calls itself before a PHP timeout until it has finished processing some data.

I understand that an ajax call reacts to a 200 status ? How could I have success only trigger when the script is done ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using deferreds. jQuery makes it quite easy to use deferreds and you can set set different callbacks for .done(), .fail(), and .always().